# TypeScript: get type of array?

Tags: arrays, typescript

I'm making a TypeScript function (fairly new to TS) that takes a parameter which can either be a number, a string, an array of numbers, or an array of strings.

I need to be able to tell the difference between those 4 in my code.

Whenever I run `typeof` on an array, it returns 'object'. How could I differentiate between an array of strings or an array of numbers in my code?

I know I could use some for loops or array methods to check the type of each index in the array, but is there a cleaner way?

```
function numToLet(input: number | number[] | string | string[]) {

if (typeof input === 'number') {
    console.log(`Input ${input} is a number.`)
}

if (typeof input === 'string') {
    console.log(`Input ${input} is a string.`)
}

if (typeof input === 'object') {
    console.log(`Input ${input} is an object. I dunno which kind though ¯\_(ツ)_/¯`)
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's the Array method Array.isArray().  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray.  I use it prolifically.  Too much, maybe.

In an old project I worked on that didn't have strict mode enabled, Array.isArray() was a great way to handle both null AND unexpected values.

```js
const myActualArray = ['apple','banana'];
const myUnArray = "apples and bananas";
let oops;

console.log(Array.isArray(myActualArray)); // true
console.log(Array.isArray(myUnArray)); // false
console.log(Array.isArray(oops)); // false
console.log(Array.isArray(null)); // false
```

Have you had a look at TypeScript generics, by the way?  I'm just beginning to ruminate on them myself, so I don't think I can speak to whether or not they provide a good TypeScript solution for you - Array.isArray() is of course just a JS solution.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Edit to add after your comment:
It seems like you're placing total faith in your code to send one of your four input types.  All you have to do is stitch together your idea of using `typeof` with Array.isArray.

```js
function numToLet(input: number | number[] | string | string[]) {

  if (typeof input === 'number') {
      console.log(`Input ${input} is a number.`)
  }

  if (typeof input === 'string') {
      console.log(`Input ${input} is a string.`)
  }

  if (Array.isArray(input)) {
      // If you're certain that your array is definitely EITHER a (non-empty) array of ALL numbers OR of ALL strings, just check the first element's type.
      if (typeof input[0] === 'number') {
        console.log(`Input ${input} is a number.`)
      }

      if (typeof input[0] === 'string') {
        console.log(`Input ${input} is a string.`)
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: After a brief skim of that article, it seems like generics are used for functions that can take any type of input, but the function can identify the type of input (unlike using the any type). I may be totally wrong but that's what it seems like.
I'd like to keep the explicit type requirement of my function for good practice, so I don't think that's the answer for my situation.

Your isArray solution would work, but as you mentioned, it doesn't provide a good way for me to check the type of the array (string or number).

Comment: There's no way to be certain of an array's type in Typescript outside of using the `.isArray()` method *and* iterating over each item in the array and checking its type.  Remember, TS is a superset of regular old JS, which simply has arrays as objects.  And given bidirectional interoperability with JS (TS compiles down to JS), the only way to ensure that an array contains only elements of a certain type is to check them manually (which includes using the `every()` method).

Comment: @JoshSilveous - I edited my answer.  You just have to stitch together your way of checking single inputs within an array iterator if you know the iterator is an array.  Or if you are completely confident that your arrays are homogeneous, then just check the first element.